# SSRS Unable to Login and Deploy

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting, bids

All, a peculiarity has shown up in SSRS. We have an ASP.NET 4.0 Web Application which interfaces with SSRS's ReportServer. Our reports are all developed in BIDS 2008. Normally, I build a report, manage my deployment configuration (in this case, 01 - Dev), and then deploy using the credentials provided by my server admin. No problem, right?

However, when I came in today to try and deploy changes to a report (so, not a new report), I made my changes, selected the report, and hit 'deploy.'

The normal login box never popped up to prompt me for my UN/PWD, and this error appeared:
"Error  1   The permissions granted to user '' are insufficient for performing this operation.      0   0"

[image: No login box]

Note that I have NOT removed my username from the above error - this is exactly how it appeared in BIDS. I checked with my server admin, and my deployment path, and all the options in the project's configuration seem to be correct, but the issue persists.

I've tried going online directly to the Report Server, and I can login just fine there and all my usual privileges seem to be in order.

I never even had a change to login.
Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What happens after you shut down the solution, delete any *.user or *.suo file, then start the solution and try again? Also try a full Rebuild Solution at various points and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: Just tried it - deleting the *.user and *.suo files didn't have any effect. (I did try Rebuilding after I tried to deploy post-deletion and before I tried to deploy - no dice). Thanks for the idea, though!

Comment: What's "normal login box"?  I've never seen one at that point. I suspect you need to start BIDS "As Administrator".

Answer (score 0):

Sorry can't comment yet from low rep, but I've had this error before and it's on the SSRS server side because I have a custom report deployment tool and it has that error returned to the client.  The solution is to play with the rights (remove and add some again) and it goes away.  I have no idea what actually causes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your report solution folder> Right click for properties > General Tab > remove 'Read only' check box. Then in the 'Security' tab, make sure all the permissions are allowed to the particular User role.
Hope it helps !